# Adding data from dictionary to RDD row

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have data frame and dictionary as shown below :

I am converting this  to RDD   and then to each row I need to copy the data from dictionary result to each Row .

THis is just  an example , I am having more than 15 keys in dictionary( which is coming as a result of some logic) which needs to get copied to dataframe .

Can some one please help and explain how can we do it dynamically with  RDD ?

```
 d =[{"curr_col1": '75757', "curr_col2": 'hello',"curr_col3": 79,"curr_col4": 'pb',"curr_col45": None,"E_N": None}

df = spark.createDataFrame(d)

dict= {'curr_col45':'55','E_N':'55}
```

Output dataframe should be

```
d =[{"curr_col1": '75757', "curr_col2": 'hello',"curr_col3": 79,"curr_col4": 'pb',"curr_col45": '55',"E_N": '55'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just map each row to a new row with the updated values from the dictionary, and then convert the `RDD` back to a `DataFrame`

Here is how you could do it:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

d = [{"curr_col1": '75757', "curr_col2": 'hello',"curr_col3": 79,"curr_col4": 'pb',"curr_col45": None,"E_N": None}]
df = spark.createDataFrame(d)

new_dict = {'curr_col45':'55','E_N':'55'}

rdd = df.rdd.map(lambda row: row.asDict())

new_rdd = rdd.map(lambda row: Row(**{k: new_dict[k] if k in new_dict and new_dict[k] is not None else row[k] for k in row}))

new_df = spark.createDataFrame(new_rdd)

new_df.show()
```

Comment: Hello @saxtheowl Thanks . Just wanted to add bit more complexity here what if there is some column in row for which dictionary is not providing data  and it remains Null . THen Row(** Dictionary) is not working .  getting this error ```ValueError: Some of types cannot be determined by the first 100 rows, please try again with sampling```

Comment: For this you can modify the Row creation code to use getattr(row, k) instead of row[k] to access the value of each column